# Prototyping for easier function firing

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

So I've creating a small library of JavaScript functions that I will be using. Some are for UI functions others are to return something. Below I will post two codes, I am wondering if this method is ok and not a bad move before going any further with this library, also please do not mention jQuery as this is all JavaScript!

```
HTMLElement.prototype.drag = function(bool) {   
var self = this;
self.classList.add('draggable');
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var origLeft= parseInt(self.offsetLeft,10);
    var origTop = parseInt(self.offsetTop,10);
    var mdX = event.clientX;
    var mdY = event.clientY;
    var elements = [];
    if(bool === true){
      var j = window.localStorage.getItem('userSettings');
      if(j){
        self.style.left= j.left;
        self.style.top = j.top;
      }
    }
      function drag(bool) {
        self.style.position="absolute";
        self.style.zIndex=999;
        self.style.left = origLeft + event.clientX - mdX + "px";
        self.style.top = origTop + event.clientY - mdY + "px";
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      function stop(bool){
        self.classList.remove('draggable');
        self.style.zIndex=0;
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove',drag,true);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup',stop,true);
           if(bool === true){
            var settings = {
              left: self.style.left,
              top: self.style.top
            };
            var b = JSON.stringify(settings);
            window.localStorage.setItem('userSettings',b);
            console.log(b);
            }
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
       document.addEventListener('mousemove',drag,true);
       document.addEventListener('mouseup',stop,true);  
};
```

The above code is of course for a `draggable` function, below is a `getClientRects()` sort of function but better.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.getRect = function(){
     var a = this.offsetLeft;
     var b = this.offsetTop;
     var c = this.offsetHeight + b;
     var d = this.offsetWidth + a;
     var f = this.offsetHeight;
     var g = this.offsetWidth;
     var obj = { };
     obj.left = a;
     obj.right=d;
     obj.top=b;
     obj.bottom=c;
     obj.width = g;
     obj.height=f;
  return obj;
};
```

Purpose of showing you all this is to get your thoughts and maybe advice about prototype or should I not do it this way. I just like the method execution like this `document.getElementById('div').getRect();` instead of doing it with a function `getRect('div');`

Comment: Extending host objects is not a good idea, see [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: Making them enumerable is quite bad, as that makes it show up when iterating using a `for-in` loop.

Comment: I think this belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: If done **carefully** extending natives can be ok; http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/extending-javascript-natives/

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy not very good at terminology, so making them enumerable not sure what you mean?

Comment: @RobG so you are basically saying to create a class function? Which is what I don't like :D as it looks incredibly annoying, and I am trying to write this library to extend to my users. What do you believe is the best choice of option? I'll make a copy of this to codereview.stackexchange and see what happens.

Comment: moved here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33901/extending-dom-elements-with-prototype-for-easier-function-execution